# Play a sound across sessions

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I made myself a small chat client for fun, that I use with my father who's just learning how this all works. Anyway, I wanted to have a button that would play a sound across the logged in sessions. If, say - my whole family is logged in to chat, I need that sound to be heard by all of them.

What I have is... well, I have a button that plays the sound when I click it, but I'm the only one who hears it.

Is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
        <input name="play" type="button" id="play" value="Attention!" onclick="playme('sounds/cartoon.wav')">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
  function playme (url){
        var audio=document.createElement("audio");
        audio.src=url;
        audio.play();
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that your chat is server based. When you click the button you need to notify the server, the server must then notify the connected clients that they must play the sound.

Comment: ok... how do I go about doing that?

Comment: You write some server side code to accept said message from a client and client side code to send said message and to listen for a notification. The server side code, when it receives message will see which clients are connected and send a notification to each. When the client receives a notify message, you have client code play a sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go across this by importing jquery in the head so

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then for your javascript

```
<script>
function playme(url){
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: 'process.php',
data: {url: url},
async : true,
success: function(resp){
}
});
</script>
```

Then for your process.php

```
<?php
file_put_contents("audio.txt", $_POST['url']);
?>
```

and finally in your javascript add

```
<script>
var check=setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "audio.txt",
type: 'POST',
async: true,
complete: function(resp){
    var res = resp["responseText"];
    var audio=document.createElement("audio");
    audio.src = res;
    audio.play();

    }
});
},100);
</script>
```

This will keep on playing the sound over and over for whoever has the page open. To avoid the complexities of checking who is online I suggest just adding another input box to clear the sound

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name = "clear" onClick="clear()">
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function clear(){
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'clear.php',
success: function(resp){
}
});
</script>
```

in clear.php

```
<?php 
file_put_contents("audio.txt", "");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically plays a message when you click a button not when you send the message.

Assuming this should really be a simple chat client without jquery or xmlhttprequest, and that you're keeping track of received messages in `$_SESSION`, then what you need to do is to compare received message on your php form with saved message and add javascript to play audio if new message received. E.g.

```
if($_SESSION('last_message') != $input_message)
{
    echo '<script>window.onload = playme</script>';
}
```